# For x function in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any way to loop through file names in XSLT (**for** function?)?

I want to check if file exists from _001.jpg ...to... _005.jpg

Currently I can check one file:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xs fs" version="2.0" xmlns:fs="java.io.File" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="DESCRIPTION" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:variable name="imageproductid" select="code"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="fs:exists(fs:new(concat('/images/',$imageproductid,'_001.jpg')))">
        <IMAGE1>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('/images/',$imageproductid,'_001.jpg')"/>
        </IMAGE1>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where `<IMAGE1>` tag should be `<IMAGE1>,<IMAGE2>,<IMAGE3>,<IMAGE4>,<IMAGE5>`

I am using Saxon 9.1, XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the alternative `<xsl:for-each>` notation to loop over a set of integers:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 5">
   ... '.' will be an integer from 1 to 5 here
</xsl:for-each>
```

To create the filename from this, use

```
... fs:exists(fs:new(concat('/images/',$imageproductid,'_00', ., '.jpg')
```

and to create a properly named new element, use `<xsl:element>`:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('IMAGE', .)}">
   .. <IMAGEx> contents ..
</xsl:element>
```

You need the notation `{..}` here because `name` must be a valid QName ([W3C, "11.2 Creating Element Nodes Using `xsl:element`"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-element)), which I take as "the *literal* text must be a valid possible element name".

Putting that together, you end up with this concise code:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:apply-templates />

    <xsl:variable name="imageproductid" select="code" />

    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 5">
        <xsl:variable name="filename"
             select="concat('/images/',$imageproductid,'_00', ., '.jpg')" />
        <xsl:if test="fs:exists(fs:new($filename))">
            <xsl:element name="{concat('IMAGE', .)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is perfect: fast and simple.